Имеет ли смысл ставить NGINX между клиентом и докер-демоном?
Сейчас схема такая:

Имеет ли смысл ставить NGINX перед DOCKER? Или можно просто поднять дополнительный контейнер NGINX в ДОКЕР и он уже пусть сам там маршрутизирует также как обычный NGINX на хосте? Или это уже избыточно и не к чему?
